# Howto do reference to ints by name in Python

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, standard-library

I want to have a a reference that reads as "whatever variable of name 'x' is pointing to" with ints so that it behaves as:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = (a, b)
>>> c
(1, 2)
>>> a = 3
>>> c
(3, 2)
```

I know I could do something similar with lists by doing:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [2]
>>> c = (a, b)
>>> c
([1], [2])
>>> a[0] = 3
>>> c
([3], [2])
```

but this can be easily lost if one assigns **a** or **b** to something instead of their elements.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I think you already pointed out the closest you're gonna get. If this is core to what you are doing, maybe a different language would suit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a direct way to do this in Python. The reason is that both scalar values (numbers) and tuples are *immutable*. Once you have established a binding from a name to an immutable value (such as the name `c` with the tuple `(1, 2)`), nothing you do except reassigning `c` can change the value it's bound to.

Note that in your second example, although the tuple is itself immutable, it contains references to mutable values. So it *appears* as though the tuple changes, but the identity of the tuple remains constant and only the mutable parts are changing.

Comment: Indeed the tuple use might be misleading, since I'm after indirect mutability after all. Even though the reference itself should be immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever possible solution you come up with the second last line will always destroy it:

```
a = 3
```

This will assign a completely new content to the variable. Unless `a` stands for a property of an object or something (or a key in a list, as you did in your own example), you won't be able to have a relation between the first and last `a`.

Comment: +1 to use of @property although the reference becomes the function call not the actual int.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the current values to be placed in a tuple on the fly you could use a lambda.  You'll have to call c, not just return it or use it, but that may be acceptable in your situation.  Something like this:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = lambda: (a, b)
>>> c()
(1, 2)
>>> a = 3
>>> c()
(3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way in Python, not only because numbers are immutable, but also because you don't have pointers. Wrapping the value in a list simulates that you have pointers, so that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ByRefValue(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Pass it around wherever you like, remembering that you need to access the `value` member rather than the entire object.

---

Alternatively, `globals().get('a', 0)` will return the value of `a` if it is in the global namespace (or zero if it isn't).

---

Finally:

```
import threading
tls = threading.local()

tls.a = 1
```

If you import `tls` into every module where you need it, you will access the same value for `a` *on each thread*. Depending on how your program is set up, this may be acceptable, ideal or useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating your own pointer class and your own pointer storage object to emulate the system's internal stack.

Comment: You're entirely correct if you don't mind using an unusual programming style and not being able to do pointer arithmetic.